# Automatic thumbnail From first image in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Is there any way to get auto thumbnails from `WP Post Image` using `BBcode`?

```
Choice: [img] image url [/img]
```

Comment: Are you a developer looking to implement this? Or are you a user looking for a plugin? If the former, can you provide the code you’ve tried, or where you got stuck? If the latter, this would be better suited for [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wordpress) or [Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wordpress).

Comment: In fact, I am a simple web developer and a web learner, I want to know through this question that if I use to show image on my post using this 
    [img]//i.mg/image.png[/img]
 bbcode in a post on my WordPress site, the first of these images will appear as a thumbnail.

Comment: Is there any way to get auto thumbnails by this way?